# How can i remove element in postgresql json[]

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

[image]

in picture the column `node_info` was the type of json[], and now i want to
remove one element of the array by Nodejs ORM `sequelize`

```
function demo(){
  const removeQuery = {
    where: {
      name: _name
    },
    raw: true
  }
 const updateNode = {
node_info: db.sequelize.fn('array_remove', db.sequelize.col('node_info'), JSON.stringify({uuid: uuid}))
 }
 db.Config.update(updateNode, removeQuery);
}
```

but i got this error:

> ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
>   Query failed
>   PostgreSQL said: could not identify an equality operator for type json

I'd appreciate any help you could give me!

Thanks :)